# Гипертония 2-й стадии(,) 2-й степени. Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая в диагнозе?

Гипертоническая болезнь 2-й стадии(,) 2-й степени.

Answer (score 3):

Запятая *нужна*. Поскольку обе характеристики относятся непосредственно к "гипертонической болезни" (взаимно независимы по смыслу), они грамматически однородны (имеет место их перечисление). При отсутствии же запятой "2-я стадия" воспринимается как частный случай "2-й степени", что не соответствует действительности.

**P. S.** Пример из книги: Аутодонорство и аутогемотрансфузии, под ред. А.А. Рагимова

> *Гипертоническая болезнь II степени, 3-й стадии, высокой степени риска.*
>   https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=9natHAIh7ZcC&hl=ru&pg=PA82&img=1&zoom=3&sig=ACfU3U1ibH_6Vt0pDirJOuAkubZd6QDvdA&w=1280

Пример заголовка истории болезни, выложенной для студентов в интернете:

> История болезни: Гипертоническая болезнь 2 стадии, 3-ей степени

http://med-books.by/istorii_vnutrennie-bolezni/6375-istoriya-bolezni-gipertonicheskaya-bolezn-2-stadii-3-ey-stepeni.html

Answer (score 3):

Профессиональная терминология может иметь свои особенности. Но если исходить из общих понятий, то следует писать так:

**Гипертоническая болезнь 2-й степени во 2-й стадии.**

Беглый анализ текстов текстов в Нацкорпусе и интернете показывает, что у врачей принято писать так:

*Гипертоническая болезнь II стадии 2 степени.*

Добавляя буквенное наращение, получаем:

**Гипертоническая болезнь II стадии 2-й степени.**

[Когда нужны буквенные наращения после цифр?](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/87-rubric-99)

> Наращение (буквенное падежное окончание) используется в записи порядковых числительных: 10-й класс «Б»; ученик 11-го класса; 1-й вагон из центра; 5-й уровень сложности; занять 2-е и 3-е места; в начале 90-х годов, 12-й маршрут.

Для справки:

> Гипертоническая болезнь – классификация основывается на следующих критериях:
>   1.Стадия – определяет тяжесть сопутствующих патологий и обширность поражения физиологических систем.
>   2.Степень – отражает средний уровень кровяного давления на протяжении суток
>   Источник: https://womanadvice.ru/gipertonicheskaya-bolezn-vse-chto-nuzhno-znat-o-povyshennom-davlenii